# Plot marker at one point instead of start and end point in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, marker, markers

I have a graph made up of lines with markers, however, I'm getting something that looks like this:[image]

I was wondering if there was a was to get the marker plotted at only the start point of the line rather than both the start and the end?

I can't seem to find anything on this anywhere so hopefully someone can help me!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to extract a minimum working example (one line instead of a graph) and show the corresponding code. Otherwise it's hard to tell, what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps not the prettiest solution, but it works; simply set `markevery` to a number equal to or larger than the array length:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(121)
pl.plot(x, y, '-o', markersize=30)
pl.subplot(122)
pl.plot(x, y, '-o', markersize=30, markevery=x.size)
```

[image]